# On Textarea Text Selection add Sticky Notes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have text area on which I want to show sticky notes to write comments and on stick notes click it should highlight associated selected text  Below is the code showing stick notes and text area to select text and on comment button click event I am getting selected text but not able to link selected text with sticky notes and not able to show notes on every comment click

[Sticky Notes Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nutvt/42/)

```js
function ShowSelection() {
    var textComponent = document.getElementById('textArea');
    var selectedText;
    // IE version
    if (document.selection != undefined) {
        textComponent.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    }
    // Mozilla version
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
        var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    alert("You selected: " + selectedText);
    
}
```

```html
<div><textarea class="Test" id="textArea" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">Hello</textarea></div>
<input type="button" value="Comment" />
```